# 404 errors in IIS most of the time while the page is

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, iis, http-status-code-404

i hope you are good and have nice day.

i working a automation web site .in a page i have chart .frist i used chart.js
then i used RGrafh for displaying charts in web page .

my website is in asp.net 4.0 non mvc (webforms).

in this page some times web page loaded whitout problem but
in often (70%) 404 error rasie . after referesh page loaded without problem.
in this page i have xhr request that dont work in iis at all.

i going crazy. i dont know what is problem .that works in local perfectly....

Comment: Can you post your code, so that we have enough idea what you have tried to do?

Comment: thanks .i found what is problem

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone.
i found problem . my partner set word to deny in request flitering in iis 7
i removed .now my page worked .

for Remove a deny form Request flitering .

GO to IIS .Request Flitering - rules